# Fit long table into page

Tags: tables, tabulary

I have this long table that I cannot make it fit in the page. I tried to turn the page in landscape and it helped a bit but the problem is still that I can't wrap the text when it is longer than the column width. Does anyone know how to fix it?
here's the code

```
    \pagestyle{plain}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Additive manufacturing technologies.}
\label{tab:am_processes}
    \begin{tabulary}{1\linewidth}{| L | L | L | L | L | L |}
    \hline
    Process & Build size & Tolerance & Materials & Layer thickness & Build rate\\
    \hline
    FDM & 914x610x914mm \cite{fdm_spec} & \pm 0.0015 up to 0.241mm & ABS, PC, PA, PS, thermoplastics & 127-330 \mu m & 7.62-43.18mm/h \cite{sculpteo_speed}\cite{fdm_info} \\
    SLA  & 650x750x550 mm  & 0.025-0.5mm &  Thermoplastics (elastomers) & 50-125\mu m & 0.635-9.52m/s \cite{pham2012rapid}\\
    Polyjet & 294x192x148.6mm \cite{polyjet_info} & \pm 0.1mm \cite{polyjet_info} & 0.015-0.030mm \cite{SLS_Polyjet} & Acrylic plastics and elastomers \cite{Fischer2014} & Fast \cite{Fischer2014}\\
    LOM & 813x559x508mm & \pm 0.127mm & 0.076-0.254mm & Thermoplastics, paper, composites (ferrous/non-ferrous metals, ceramics) & - \\
    SLS & 550x550x750 mm & \pm 0.3mm &  polyamide based compounds (nylon) & 120-150 \mu m & 0.6 to 2.5 cm\textsuperscript{3}/h\\
    EBM & 200x200x350mm &\pm 0.2mm & Metals (cobalt, nickel, titanium) & 50 \mu m & 45-66mm\textsuperscript{3}/s\\
    LENS & 900x1500x900mm & \pm 0.125mm & metals (titanium, nickel-base superalloys, stainless steels and tool steels) & 120 \mu m & 5-60 mm\textsuperscript{3}/s\\
    3DP & 254x381x203mm & \pm 0.2mm &  Ferrous/non-ferrous metals, elastomeric, composites, ceramics & 90-100 \mu m & 25-50 mm\textsuperscript{3}/h\\
    Prometal & 1800x1000x700mm (sand) 750x400x400 (metal) & \pm 0.125 & Sand, glass, metal & 280-500 \mu m & 2000(metal) to 30000(sand) mm\textsuperscript{3}/s\\
    \end{tabulary}
    \caption*{Data was obtained by \cite{Aliakbari2012} unless otherwise indicated}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: It seems that you're not generous enough in your use of white space. For example, 914x610x914mm would benefit from being rewritten to 914 $\times$ 610 $\times$ 914mm. This would allow for many more places to break. Also, you keep forgetting switching to math mode - \pm should be $\pm$, \mu should be $\mu$, etc.

Comment: please always post a complete document that shows the problem, in particular here  you give no indication of the page size onto which you need to fit this table.

Comment: Actually, he does. He wants to fit the text into 1\linewidth. (The 1 is superflous.)

Comment: @roffe and `\linewidth` is?? the width of what, A4, US-letter, a5?, with what margins....

Comment: Does it matter? The user obviously struggles with overfull hboxes, since he's worring about text wrapping.  \linewidth is a dimension variable that, as I assume you know, is related to the width of the current line. So it's reasonable to assume that the user would like his table to span the full with of a normal page and that if he wouldn't, he'd say so. His use of \pagestyle{plain} indeed indicates that he wants as little fuss as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, tested with latex + dvipdf, and pdflatex. xelatex probably requires some tweaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,rotating}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{sidewaystable}[]
  \centering
  \caption{Additive manufacturing technologies.}
  \label{tab:am_processes}
  \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{| L | L | L | L | L | L |}
hline
    Process & Build size & Tolerance & Materials & Layer thickness & Build rate\\
    \hline
    FDM & 914 $\times$ 610 $\times$ 914 mm \cite{fdm_spec} & $\pm$ 0.0015 up to 0.241 mm & ABS, PC, PA, PS, thermoplastics & 127-330 $\mu$ m & 7.62-43.18 mm/h \cite{sculpteo_speed}\cite{fdm_info} \\
    SLA  & 650 $\times$ 750 $\times$ 550  mm  & 0.025-0.5 mm &  Thermoplastics (elastomers) & 50-125$\mu$ m & 0.635-9.52m/s \cite{pham2012rapid}\\
    Polyjet & 294 $\times$ 192 $\times$ 148.6 mm \cite{polyjet_info} & $\pm$ 0.1 mm \cite{polyjet_info} & 0.015-0.030 mm \cite{SLS_Polyjet} & Acrylic plastics and elastomers \cite{Fischer2014} & Fast \cite{Fischer2014}\\
    LOM & 813 $\times$ 559 $\times$ 508 mm & $\pm$ 0.127 mm & 0.076-0.254 mm & Thermoplastics, paper, composites (ferrous/non-ferrous metals, ceramics) & - \\
    SLS & 550 $\times$ 550 $\times$ 750  mm & $\pm$ 0.3 mm &  polyamide based compounds (nylon) & 120-150 $\mu$ m & 0.6 to 2.5 cm\textsuperscript{3}/h\\
    EBM & 200 $\times$ 200 $\times$ 350 mm &$\pm$ 0.2 mm & Metals (cobalt, nickel, titanium) & 50 $\mu$ m & 45-66 mm\textsuperscript{3}/s\\
    LENS & 900 $\times$ 1500 $\times$ 900 mm & $\pm$ 0.125 mm & metals (titanium, nickel-base superalloys, stainless steels and tool steels) & 120 $\mu$ m & 5-60  mm\textsuperscript{3}/s\\
    3DP & 254 $\times$ 381 $\times$ 203 mm & $\pm$ 0.2 mm &  Ferrous/non-ferrous metals, elastomeric, composites, ceramics & 90-100 $\mu$ m & 25-50  mm\textsuperscript{3}/h\\
    Prometal & 1800 $\times$ 1000 $\times$ 700 mm (sand) 750 $\times$ 400 $\times$ 400 (metal) & $\pm$ 0.125 & Sand, glass, metal & 280-500 $\mu$ m & 2000(metal) to 30000(sand)  mm\textsuperscript{3}/s\\
  \end{tabulary}


    \caption*{Data was obtained by \cite{Aliakbari2012} unless otherwise indicated}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it also with `sidewaystable`, but using `tabularx`, threeparttable`and`siunitx`. If the table has to break across pages, you can load`ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of`longtable`to`tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, array}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage{rotating, caption, threeparttable, tabularx, makecell, ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\let\nl\newline

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}\small
  \sisetup{range-phrase=--,range-units =single}
  \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Additive manufacturing technologies.}
    \label{tab:am_processes}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| p{1.4cm}| l| l |>{\hsize=1.12\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} X| >{\hsize=1.12\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|>{\hsize=0.76\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X |}
      \hline
      Process & \makecell{Build size (mm)} \\
      \hline
      FDM & $ 914 × 610 × 914 $ \cite{fdm_spec} \\ to \SI{0.241}{mm}} & ABS, PC, PA, PS, thermoplastics & \SIrange{127}{330}{\um} & \SIrange{7.62}{43.18}{mm/h} \cite{sculpteo_speed}\cite{fdm_info} \\
      SLA & $ 650 × 750 × 550 $ \\
      Polyjet & $ 294 × 192 × 148.6 $ \cite{polyjet_info} \\
      LOM & $ 813 × 559 × 508 $ \\
      SLS & $ 550 × 550 × 750 $ \\
      EBM & $ 200 × 200 × 350 $ \\
      LENS & $ 900 × 1500 × 900 $ \\
      3DP & $ 254 × 381 × 203 $ \\
      Prometal & \makecell[tl]{$ 1800 × 1000 × 700 $ \\ (sand)\\l $ 750 × 400 × 400 $\\ (metal)} & $±0.125$ & Sand, glass, metal & \SIrange{280}{500}{\um} & 2000 (metal) to 30000 (sand) \si{mm³/s}\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \medskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
      \item[]Data was obtained by \cite{Aliakbari2012} unless otherwise indicated. \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
      \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]